# PHP, strip out Currency symbol before posting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue when posting the £ symbol to my DB it seems to add some strange characters before it. I've decided that the best thing to do is to strip the symbol before it goes in to the DB and add it back in again when I read the data.

Is there a simple PHP function that will take my $variable, take out that specific character before I send it and then create a new $variable_new that I can send to the DB.

Thanks, Jonny

Comment: please point out why none of these helped solve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+character+from+string+php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for.

`$variable_new = str_replace('£','',$variable);`

Comment: saves searching the whole string: `substr($variable, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and best) solution is probably to get your character encodings right. First make sure you've got the web browser sending you stuff in utf-8

Then make sure your database is storing utf-8 or is encoding ignostic. I know MySQL cares about character encoding and that conversion happens (somewhere, in PHP and/or MySQL) if your character set isn't right.

I put: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

in my .htaccess file for all sites to be sure all data is sent to me in UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function ***from within your query***:

```
SUBSTRING(fieldName FROM 1)
```

Or check out:

- [Turning MySQL data in latin1 to utf8 utf-8](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html)

To know how to change the charset of your database to support symbols.

Comment: I tried to do this changing MySQL to utf-8 but it did not seem to solve the problem. I'm not sure what is going on. When my INSERT query runs and there is the £ symbol it just seems to add a Â£100 before the symbol

Answer (score 0):

I would use [string replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as a quick solution, but ideally I would never add the symbol to the variable in the first place.

```
$newvar = str_replace('£', '', $oldvar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), or you could use preg_replace to replace all non-numeric/dot/comma characters. However, I don't think either one is the best solution.

I think it would be best to alter your script so that the symbol is never tacked on to the numerical value in the first place. Do keep track of the symbol though, and perhaps store it in a separate column in the database so you know what currency was used. Having a strictly numerical value allows you to (more easily) do more that you might want in the future.